# How to read screen information from QGuiApplication to put in qputenv environment variable?

Tags: c++, qt, ppi

Aim is to run this application on screens with different PPI.

Qt 5.12

The problem is that `qputenv` does not work if written after the initialization of `QGuiApplication`.

I want to calculate scale according to the information from QGuiApplication.

How do I do it? The following code throws a segmentation fault.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qreal abc = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch();

    qDebug() << "null " << abc;

    qputenv("QT_SCALE_FACTOR", "2");

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think you cannot modify the environment after a process is started - it will still pick the "old" variables.